# jquery datepicker calendar - populate with mysql vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I Currently have events set in my datepicker based of my filter.js file that uses something like:

```
var events = [ 
{ Title: "1", Date: new Date("12/4/2010") }, 
{ Title: "2", Date: new Date("12/10/2010") }
```

];

I have these dates stored in a mysql db and I need to pull the dates from it instead of a static js file. Dates can be added, changed, etc.

I'm using vb .net

Answer (score 1):

Suggest creating a web service that serves your latest events/dates. Then your JavaScript code can call into that web service.

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebMethod> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat := ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function GetDates() As String
   'return a collection as you need
End Function
```

On the JS side, [call this web service using jQuery](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/):

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourWebServiceURL.aspx/GetDates",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {

      var events ; //get your events from the msg object.
    }
  });
```

Comment: Using $.ajax gives me the impression i'm required to have ajax working on our server. We are on a university server and ajax is currently not allowed. Is this the only way of getting around this issue?

Comment: @Dom give it a shot. There's nothing really to get setup or working on your server. It just works. It's xmlhttprequest.